# Python 3.3. Concatenating strings from input. How?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple python app that asks for user input and concatenate this input with a HEX delimiter and a second input. I can do this in C# with my eyes closed but am new to Python. Care to post a sample?

Thanks a bunch,

Vini

Comment: what is "HEX delimiter"?

Comment: If you already know some other programming language then you can find [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) useful.

Comment: HEX delimiter as in ISO/IEC 646. For example: First name + 00A0 + Last Name + 00A0. Maybe these are bytes. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = input("Enter the first input:")
b = input("Enter the second input:") 
result = a + delimiter + b
# or 
# result = delimiter.join([a, b])
```

To type ["NO-BREAK SPACE" character](http://codepoints.net/U+00A0) in source code:

```
delimiter = "\u00A0"
```

If you have it as an integer:

```
delimiter = chr(0x00A0)
```